# How to filter data using JavaScript in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, filtering

I have a question about filtering data using JavaScript in react.
Please see the below data and what I'm trying to do.

```js
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "iso": "AF",
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "prefix": "33"
    },
    {
      "iso": "IE",
      "name": "Ireland",
      "prefix": "18"
    },
    {
      "iso": "DE",
      "name": "Germany",
      "prefix": "25"
    }
  ],
  "operators": [
    {
      "id": "af-internet",
      "iso": "AF",
      "name": "Afghanistan Internet"
    },
    {
      "id": "af-mobile",
      "iso": "AF",
      "name": "Afghanistan Mobile"
    },
    {
      "id": "de-mobile",
      "iso": "DE",
      "name": "Germany Mobile Operator"
    },
    {
      "id": "de-data",
      "iso": "DE",
      "name": "Germany data plans"
    },
    {
      "id": "ie-one",
      "iso": "IE",
      "name": "Ireland Mobile One"
    },
    {
      "id": "ie-two",
      "iso": "IE",
      "name": "Ireland Mobile Two"
    }
  ],
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "af-internet",
      "products": [
        "10 AFN Internet Recharge",
        "20 AFN Internet Recharge",
        "30 AFN Internet Recharge",
        "40 AFN Internet Recharge"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "af-mobile",
      "products": [
        "10 AFN Mobile",
        "20 AFN Mobile",
        "30 AFN Mobile",
        "40 AFN Mobile"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "de-mobile",
      "products": [
        "10 AFN Mobile",
        "20 AFN Mobile",
        "30 AFN Mobile",
        "40 AFN Mobile"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "de-data",
      "products": ["10 EUR Data", "20 EUR Data", "30 EUR Data", "40 EUR Data"]
    },
    {
      "id": "ie-one",
      "products": [
        "20 EUR Mobile",
        "50 EUR Mobile",
        "90 EUR Mobile",
        "120 EUR Mobile"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "ie-two",
      "products": [
        "10 EUR Mobile",
        "20 EUR Mobile",
        "30 EUR Mobile",
        "40 EUR Mobile"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So here is my logic that I tried to filter out the product.

```
let products = state.products.filter(el => el.id).map(el => el.products);
console.log(products);
```

**When I console log the product, the below is what I am getting:**

```js
(6)[Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4)["10 AFN Internet Recharge", "20 AFN Internet Recharge", "30 AFN Internet Recharge", "40 AFN Internet Recharge"]
1: (4)["10 AFN Mobile", "20 AFN Mobile", "30 AFN Mobile", "40 AFN Mobile"]
2: (4)["10 EUR Mobile", "20 EUR Mobile", "30 EUR Mobile", "40 EUR Mobile"]
3: (4)["10 EUR Data", "20 EUR Data", "30 EUR Data", "40 EUR Data"]
4: (4)["20 EUR Mobile", "50 EUR Mobile", "90 EUR Mobile", "120 EUR Mobile"]
5: (4)["10 EUR Mobile", "20 EUR Mobile", "30 EUR Mobile", "40 EUR Mobile"]
length: 6
```

But what I want to get after filtering is if the user selects ***`Afghanistan Internet operator`***,

```js
{
  "id": "af-internet",
  "products": [
    "10 AFN Internet Recharge",
    "20 AFN Internet Recharge",
    "30 AFN Internet Recharge",
    "40 AFN Internet Recharge"
  ]
}
```

if the user selects ***`Afghanistan Mobile operator`***,

```js
{
  "id": "af-mobile",
  "products": [
    "10 AFN MOBILE",
    "20 AFN MOBILE",
    "30 AFN MOBILE",
    "40 AFN MOBILE"
  ]
}

And so on until it gets to the last operator ***`Ireland Mobile Two operator`***,
```

For **Afghanistan Internet Operator** => it needs to display these products separately like below:

```
"10 AFN Internet Recharge",
"20 AFN Internet Recharge",
"30 AFN Internet Recharge",
"40 AFN Internet Recharge"
```

For **Afghanistan Mobile Operator** => it needs to display these products separately like below:

```
 "10 EUR Mobile",
 "20 EUR Mobile",
 "30 EUR Mobile",
 "40 EUR Mobile"
```

It depends on what user selects it is going to display the products based on that - 4 specific products for one specific operator.

I am having trouble display the above Recharge data specific to each operator I choose.
Would any of you know how I could filter and display this recharge data in such manner?
I want to make cards out of this so that a user would have options to choose how much they would like to recharge based on given recharge options.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!
If you have any questions or want clarification about what I am trying to do please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So if you only want to return products for a particular operator from the array, you can just do

```
const selectedOperator = "de-data";  

const operatorProducts = data.products.filter(x => x.id == 
selectedOperator)[0].products

console.info("all products for the selected operator", 
operatorProducts);
```

Comment: final result will give you an array of array which OP doesn't want.

Comment: Either you should use index to get the result or use flatMap

Comment: connect here https://meet.google.com/ahj-kdqv-tso, i'm available only for next 15-20 mins

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result using the combination of filter and flatMap.

```js
const state = {
  countries: [{
      iso: "AF",
      name: "Afghanistan",
      prefix: "33",
    },
    {
      iso: "IE",
      name: "Ireland",
      prefix: "18",
    },
    {
      iso: "DE",
      name: "Germany",
      prefix: "25",
    },
  ],
  operators: [{
      id: "af-internet",
      iso: "AF",
      name: "Afghanistan Internet",
    },
    {
      id: "af-mobile",
      iso: "AF",
      name: "Afghanistan Mobile",
    },
    {
      id: "de-mobile",
      iso: "DE",
      name: "Germany Mobile Operator",
    },
    {
      id: "de-data",
      iso: "DE",
      name: "Germany data plans",
    },
    {
      id: "ie-one",
      iso: "IE",
      name: "Ireland Mobile One",
    },
    {
      id: "ie-two",
      iso: "IE",
      name: "Ireland Mobile Two",
    },
  ],
  products: [{
      id: "af-internet",
      products: [
        "10 AFN Internet Recharge",
        "20 AFN Internet Recharge",
        "30 AFN Internet Recharge",
        "40 AFN Internet Recharge",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "af-mobile",
      products: [
        "10 AFN Mobile",
        "20 AFN Mobile",
        "30 AFN Mobile",
        "40 AFN Mobile",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "de-mobile",
      products: [
        "10 EUR Mobile",
        "20 EUR Mobile",
        "30 EUR Mobile",
        "40 EUR Mobile",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "de-data",
      products: ["10 EUR Data", "20 EUR Data", "30 EUR Data", "40 EUR Data"],
    },
    {
      id: "ie-one",
      products: [
        "20 EUR Mobile",
        "50 EUR Mobile",
        "90 EUR Mobile",
        "120 EUR Mobile",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "ie-two",
      products: [
        "10 EUR Mobile",
        "20 EUR Mobile",
        "30 EUR Mobile",
        "40 EUR Mobile",
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const idArr = [
  "af-internet",
  "af-mobile",
  "de-mobile",
  "de-data",
  "ie-one",
  "ie-two",
];
const result = state.products
  .filter((el) => idArr.includes(el.id))
  .flatMap((p) => p.products);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Gift what is your expected result? Would you include it in the question itself?